# Defining data types with power query (M) or in the data model?

Tags: types, powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I've searched for a possible answer to this question, but I can't seem to find it. Perhaps I'm asking the wrong way. Power BI offers two ways to define the data types for the fields within your data.

1. The first way is within the Power Query editor (M). Power Query automatically inserts a step to detect the data types when connecting to the source.
2. The second way is to set/change the data types on the data model from within the Power BI report design UI.

I'm wondering if it's more efficient (in terms of computer resources) to define the data types within the Power Query editor (M), or from the report design UI. I've noticed that the data refreshes quicker if I set the data types from the report design UI (and also removing the Power Query "Detect Data Type" step), but I don't understand why.

Most of what I've found is mutually exclusive, and doesn't explain how one method interacts or affects the other.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Performance is improved when you remove the "detect data Type" from the PowerQuery settings because PowerBi doesn't need to scan the every value in the column to determine the best type

Comment: @Trubs Many thanks for the comment! But if I set the data types manually within the Power Query editor (the M code is Table.TransformColumnTypes() either way), the performance is still worse than if I set the data types via the report design UI. Is it just because Power Query is slower than the report design UI method?